# Expected value of certain exponential transformation of standard normal variable 

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is in reference to the [Girsanov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem) however question is general. If $X$ is a standard normal variable $N(0,1)$, why is expectation of $e^{-\mu X - \mu^2/2}$ equal to 1?

Shouldn't it be $e^{-\mu^2/2}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we let $Y = -\mu X$, then $Y$ is distributed as $N(0, \mu^2)$, and $e^Y$ is a lognormal random variable with parameters $0, \mu^2$. The expected value of a lognormal with parameters $a, b^2$ is $e^{a + b^2/2}$, so $E(e^{-\mu X}) = E(e^Y) = e^{\mu^2/2}$. The given result follows immediately.

Comment: i computed my expectation of lognormal variable incorrectly. thanks.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  One might also observe that $\mathbb{E}[e^{t X}]$ is, by definition, the [mgf of the Standard Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and therefore equals $e^{t^2/2}$.  Set $t=-\mu$, QED.

Comment: @whuber, good comment :) I myself always turn to either chf or mgf if I see exponential transformation, it is like reflex :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right, but to make it even more fairly obvious. Imaginae Y = -muX -0.5mu^2, then it follows Y~N(-0.5mu^2,mu^2) as above, and thus expectation of lognormal is e^(-0.5mu^2+0.5mu^2) thus = e^0 = 1